# Dash-case on controllers routes with JsonApiDotNetCore

Tags: json-api

I'm trying to configure the JsonApiDotNetCore backend to communicate with my EmberJs frontend, but I have a problem with the naming convention for the controller. The backend is listening on http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articleCategories, but the frontend is requesting on http://localhost:3000/api/v1/article-categories. How can I change the routing on the backend side?

Answer (score 0):

This is documented [here](https://www.jsonapi.net/usage/options.html#custom-serializer-settings).

From `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddJsonApi<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new KebabCaseNamingStrategy()
    };
});
```